# Facebook apprequests not sending notification to non app friends

Tags: facebook, notifications, apprequests

I created a game app in facebook and invited my friends (non app friends) through apprequests. The request is properly sent to facebook and a response received after inviting a user. But notifications are not being sent while invite. I checked my app configuration. I set the canvas url. I checked the app configration. But I am still not able to understand the problem.

My request code is

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'YOUR_MESSAGE_HERE',
  action_type:'turn'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

I would like to understand how to get the notification.